# SQL function to calculate simple interest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have worked on the solution, I need some intervention to optimize the solution.

Here is my current script:

```sql
create function SI (@Principal int, @roi int , @time int)
returns int 
as 
begin 
    declare @Principal_Amt int
    --set @Principal_Amt = 10000
    set @Principal_Amt = @Principal

    declare @rate int
    --set @rate=10
    set @rate = @roi

    declare @time_period int
    --set @time_period = 5
    set @time_period = @time

    declare @Simple_Interest int
    set @Simple_Interest = @Principal_Amt * @rate * @time_period / 100

    return @Simple_Interest
end

select dbo.SI(10000, 8, 5)
```

Comment: If you care about performance, don't use a user-defined function.

Comment: That's a very sweeping statement @GordonLindoff and I don't agree with it. User-defined functions can perform very well.

Comment: clash of the titans

Comment: I agree with both. Most user-defined functions will be a performance problem 90% of the times. Except for inline table-valued functions and some exceptional scalar UDFs, I would suggest to stay out of using functions in SQL Server. (That might change with 2019 or future versions)

Answer (score 3):

It's only

```
create function SI(@Principal int = 0, @roi int = 0, @time int = 0)
returns int 
as 
begin 
return (@Principal * @roi * @time /100)
end
```

You don't need to declare those variables, since you already have them, so use them directly.

Comment: Are you sure you want all integers ?

Comment: You can add a decimal point to the 100 and prevent integer division.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I dunno if the OP want to, cause he specify `INT`